# Simplifying expressions with Big O notation

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, weak-convergence

Consider a real-valued sequence $\{h_n\}_n$ with $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}h_n=0$. Could you help me to simplify $(O(h_n^2))^2+3O(h_n^2)$?

My attempt:

(1) $(O(h_n^2))^2=h_n^4(O(1))^2=h_n^4(O(1))=O(h_n^4)$

(2) $3O(h_n^2)=O(h_n^2)$

(3) $(O(h_n^2))^2+3O(h_n^2)=O(h_n^4)+O(h_n^2)=?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $h$ is small,
$O(h^4)+O(h^2)
=O(h^2)
$
since
$\frac{h^4}{h^2}
\to 0
$
as $h \to 0$.

If $h$ is large,
$O(h^4)+O(h^2)
=O(h^4)
$
since
$\frac{h^2}{h^4}
\to 0
$
as $h \to \infty$.

Comment: thanks, I don't get the proof of $O(h^4)+O(h^2)=O(h^2)$ when $h$ small, which I guess is my case since I'm considering asymptotics for $n \rightarrow \infty$. Thanks for your help

Comment: When $h$ is small (say .001), $h^4$ (=.000000000001) is much smaller than $h^2$ (=.000001), so it can be neglected.

Comment: Could you put a formal proof using the definition of Big O?

Comment: My original statement that $\frac{h^4}{h^2} \to 0$ as $h \to 0$ should be enough.